# problem with loops in R

Tags: r, loops, statistics, histogram, raster

```
library(rgdal) 
my_asc = dir("~/Pulpit/dods/karol/TVDI113_121",
             pattern=".asc", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(my_asc)) {
    r <- readGDAL(my_asc[i])
    z <- as.matrix(r)
    vectordata[i] <- mean(z) 
    vectordatamax[i] <- max(z) 
    vectordatamin[i] <- min(z) 
    vectordev[i] <- sd(z, na.rm=TRUE) 
    hist(z)
    png(filename="hist"+tostring(i)+".png")
}
```

I try to do some modification of this loop, but it still doesn't works (I am working under Rstudio) - which fragment is incorrect?

I would like also to use more complicated pattern (to list only files which contains on the end of it name two numbers), but adding something like:
`pattern="_??.asc"` seems not works.

I would like to add one more loop to get list of folders (instead of manually inserting directories into my_asc variable), but I haven't got Idea how I can do it?
I do not know, why my way of creating vectors for mean, max, min and standard deviation values is not working...

Comment: try debugging running it without a full loop, just do one file, and while you are at it split up the three questions

Comment: Put `browser()` as your first loop line and run the loop. You are now "inside" the loop and you can see all the variables as they're created, change them, run checks and test...

Comment: There is many things going in this loop. What **exactly** doesn't works? You got error - what it say? Results are not you expect - so what you expect? You could edit your question to add more informations. For now -1.

Answer (score 2):

Where to start . . .

You probably want na.rm = TRUE for each of mean, max, and min, and you will need to enter TRUE correctly for sd.

The hist(z) should come after the png(filename, ...) and that will have to be followed by a dev.off() (at least).

You cannot paste together strings with "+" in R, use paste().

```
vectordata <- vectordatamax <- vectordatamin <- vectordev <- numeric(length(my_asc))
for (i in seq_along(my_asc)) {
  r <- readGDAL(my_asc[i])
  ## as.matrix is not necessary, as the band values are accessible directly
  ##z <- as.matrix(r)
  z <- r[[1]]
  vectordata[i] <- mean(z, na.rm=TRUE) 
  vectordatamax[i] <- max(z) 
  vectordatamin[i] <- min(z) 
  vectordev[i] <- sd(z, na.rm=TRUE) 
  png(filename=paste("hist", i, ".png", sep=""))
  hist(z)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: I started to fix some of the OP's code, then realized that you have already described in words what needs to be done, so have added code to your answer rather than creating a new answer.

Comment: cool, thanks - I would have put together a full example with data from rgdal package, but I don't know the regex for the digits in the filename part and haven't looked that up yet :)

Comment: I'll join to editors of your answer :) I add initialization result vectors cause, based on OP additional info, they might be needed.